# Cloud-init issues with variables

Tags: linux, azure, ubuntu, cloud, cloud-init

All,
I am trying to run this command in a cloud-init script on Ubuntu:
dcs=$(https://$KEYVAULTNAME.vault.azure.net/secrets/deviceConnectionString?api-version=2016-10-01 -H "Authorization: Bearer $token")

However, it does not complete as expected and when I set an echo out for dcs...what I am seeing is:

https://MyKeyvaultName.vault.azure.net/secrets/deviceConnectionString?api-version=2016-10-01

but I am not sure why it is dropping everything after the -H.

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the command like this:

```
dcs=$(curl "https://$KEYVAULTNAME.vault.azure.net/secrets/deviceConnectionString?api-version=2016-10-01" -H "Authorization: Bearer $token")
```

Then it will work for you.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I modified my cloud-init with the line that you placed above and I get the following response:

runcmd.13: {'dcs=$(curl \'https://$KEYVAULTNAME.vault.azure.net/secrets/deviceConnectionString?api-version=2016-10-01\' -H "Authorization': 'Bearer $token")'} is not valid under any of the given schemas

thoughts?

Comment: @KeithHill Sorry, that's my mistake. When you use the variable in the URL, you need to also use the double-quotes. I forget it.

Comment: Thank you for the response... I tried your suggestion:

My command is configured as:

dcs=$(curl "https://$KEYVAULTNAME.vault.azure.net/secrets/deviceConnectionString?api-version=2016-10-01" -H Authorization: Bearer $token)

However, in the cloud-init-output file I am getting this error:

runcmd.13: {'dcs=$(curl "https://$KEYVAULTNAME.vault.azure.net/secrets/deviceConnectionString?api-version=2016-10-01" -H Authorization': 'Bearer $token)'} is not valid under any of the given schemas

thoughts?

Comment: @KeithHill What about the token? As I see it's also the variable, do you use the double quotes? Or instead of all the variables with the exact value.

Comment: Thank you again for the help.  The $token is set in the line previous to this one.  It would be much easier if I could not use the variables, however, in my execution the values of the variables change from one deployment to another.

Comment: @KeithHill So when you use the double-quotes, does it work for you?